# Issues with Contentful SDK code after migration

Tags: xcode, swift3, sdk, contentful

See the code below I am having issues with. I have added most of the function even tho I am only getting the error in line 3. Just to give a better understanding of what I am trying to do.

```
func getTopArticles(_ vc: ArticleListViewController, subCatId: String) {
    var articleDict = [String: Article]()
    Constants.CLIENT.fetchEntries(["content_type":Constants.CONTENT_TYPE_ARTICLE,
        "fields.top10Listing.sys.id":subCatId, "order":Constants.SORT_CREATED_AT_DESCENDING]) { //Getting error here
        switch $0 {
        case let .success(articleResult):
            if articleResult.items.isEmpty {
                vc.noTopArticlePresent()
            }
            else{
                for articleEntry in articleResult.items {
                    let article = Article (entry:articleEntry)
                    vc.art.append(article)

                    // store into search cache
                    Constants.ARTICLE_CACHE.fetch(key: "articles").onSuccess({ (result) in
                        if let dictValue = result as? [String:Article]
                        {
                            articleDict = dictValue
                            articleDict[article.articleId] = article
                        }
                        Constants.ARTICLE_CACHE.set(value: articleDict, key: "articles")
                    }).onFailure({ (error) in
                        Constants.ARTICLE_CACHE.set(value: articleDict, key: "articles")
                    })
                }
                Constants.CACHE.set(value: NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: vc.art), key: subCatId)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    vc.dothis()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Getting error in line 3. See error below

Argument labels '(__:,_:)' do not match any available overloads

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the argument label `matching` for the method call.

The function signature is `fetchEntries(matching:completion)`

Taking your example above, and adding the our call would look like the following:

```
    Constants.CLIENT.fetchEntries(matching:
 ["content_type": Constants.CONTENT_TYPE_ARTICLE,
            "fields.top10Listing.sys.id":subCatId, "order":Constants.SORT_CREATED_AT_DESCENDING]) { (result: Result<ArrayResponse<Entry>>) in // Or anonymous argument $0 as you were using in your example.
```

Generally, if you see an error telling you argument labels don't match, you can find the declaration in the source and compare to see if you have a mismatch with the naming of your arguments being passed in. See more about argument labels and parameter names in Swift [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID166).